# How to move to Socket.io v1.x from v0.9.x

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an application under development which uses socket.io to establish Web RTC connections between multiple clients. The application was developed by another developer and I am taking it over for now. One of the things I want to do is move from socket.io v0.9.16 which is being currently used to the most up to date version v1.3.5.

I have looked at the [page](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/) on migrating from v0.9 to v1.0 and tried changing a few things, however it does not seem to work for me. I am getting the following error in the chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED https://143.167.117.93:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1435567474680
```

indicating that there has been a problem with the socket.io initialisation. The code below shows the way it is being done currently, which works with socket.io v0.9.16.

```
var protocol = require('https');
var portNo = 3000;
var app = protocol.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

    /**
     * server serves pages otherwise 404.html
     */
    file.serve(req, res, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
        console.error('Error serving %s - %s', req.url, err.message);
            if (err.status === 404 || err.status === 500) {
                file.serveFile(util.format('/%d.html', err.status), err.status, {}, req, res);
            } else {
                res.writeHead(err.status, err.headers);
                res.end();
            }
        } else {
            console.log('serving %s ', req.url);
        }
    });
}).listen(portNo);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app, {
    log: false,
    origins: '*:*'
});

io.set('transports', [
    'websocket',
    'xhr-polling',
    'jsonp-polling'
]);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    //Do something
});
```

If you need any more information to complete this question please let me know. I have limited experience using socket.io and node.js so I apologise if the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not setting correctly socket.io and you are still using some options from socket.io 0.9 version. Try to create a basic example using [socket.io migration tutorial](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/), below it is an example of using `http` node.js library along with `socket.io 1.x` library.

`app.js` file:

```
var protocol = require('http').createServer(handler);
var file = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(protocol);
var portNo = 4040;

protocol.listen(portNo, function() {
  console.log('server up and running');
});

function handler(req, res) {
  file.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.send('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.emit('message', 'you just connected dude!');
});
```

---

`index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.js">
    </script>

    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();

      socket.on('message', function(message) {
        alert(message);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```